# How to show cpu usage in cloudfoundry cf-cli

Tags: cloud-foundry

As the title, how to show CPU usage in cloud foundry cli?

I am able to see the CPU usage once when I deploy for the first time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cf app APP-NAME` to show the view you’ve posted there after an app start.